# What is the proper GPRS / GSM modem setup to work with 5 voltage sensors?

Tags: voltage, gsm, modem

I've been looking at modems and most of them come in RS232/485 input only. I need to hook up 5 different power cables to the modem to monitor their voltage.

Some of the modem's I've found have 4 to 8 digital and analog input/output. I've also looked at maybe having an Arduino in between the modem and sensors.

What is the proper GPRS / GSM modem setup for 5 voltage sensors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a GPS tracker - [here's](http://www.bridgat.com/gps_tracker_built_in_2_analog_inputs-o53602.html) one that has (amongst other features): -

- Programmable logging and upload interval
- 4 x alarm inputs
- 2 x analog inputs [GS902]
- 2 x relay outputs
- 1 x low voltage alert

It doesn't give you the full 5 analogue inputs you need but it's a start.

[image]